# Beautiful Soup AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' even though webpage is structured the same

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

so I have working code for one web-scraper and want to use it on another website which is structured the same.

The code I have that works is:

```
url = "https://efl.network/index/efl/LeaguePassingStats.html"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
tb = soup.find('table', class_='tablesorter')
table_rows = tb.find_all("tr")
```

however if i change the `url` to

`https://sim-football.com/indexes/DSFLS22/LeaguePassingStats.html`

it gives me the error

```
table_rows = tb.find_all("tr")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Both websites seem to be structured the same however.

Answer (score 0):

This line returns None

```
tb = soup.find('table', class_='tablesorter')
```

That means, there is no table element with class 'tablesorter' on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you print out `page.content` you can see this is the HTML that is returned: `'<head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>'`

So the website is blocking your web scrape for some reason and returning this error HTML, in which the `table` element you're looking for doesn't exist, causing your error